# Wrong encoding when read blob to string using Hibernate 4 and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, blob

I have an entity with field:

```
@Column
String shortVarcharField;

@Column(columnDefinition = "BLOB", length = 65534)
private String veryLongStringInBlob;
```

when I'm store this entity to database and watch it with MySQL-CLI, I see normal UTF there. But when I read it with Hibrnate, it reads `��` instead normal unicode.

So, how I should change my entity to normally map long strings to blob?

Answer (score 0):

use `@Lob` annotation in entity before veriable. `@Lob` use for the trick for blob and clob (use String as type). you can refer bellow reference code.

```
@Column( name = "FILEIMAGE" )
@Lob(type = LobType.BLOB)
private byte[] fileimage;
```

you can also use this bellow code :

```
@Column(name="content")
@Lob
private Blob content;
```

Comment: unfortunally, it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Solution is quite simple:

```
@Column
String shortVarcharField;

@Column(columnDefinition = "BLOB", length = 65534)
private byte[] veryLongStringInBlob;

public String getVeryLongStringInBlob(){
  return new String(veryLongStringInBlob);
}

public void setVeryLongStringInBlob(String value){
  this.setVeryLongStringInBlob = value.getBytes();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read that BLOB column as byte[] and construct a String using UTF-8 charset from that byte[], something like below in your model

```
@Lob 
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
@Column(name="YOURCOLUMN", columnDefinition="BLOB", nullable = true)
private byte[] info;


public String getInfo() {
    try {
        return (new String(info,"UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}

public void setInfo(byte[] info) {
    this.info = info;
}
```